# JMX initialization in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-jmx

I have a Java class which I am running from Eclipse.

I want to implement jmx counters on the Eclipse and not on the jconsole.

The class doesn't have any jmx initialization or spring initialization.
It's a normal Java class .

Is there any API which I can copy in my Java class and add a applicationContext.xml in the main/src/resources in the Java class.

I just want to implement an API so that I can display my jmx counters using @managaAttribute on the Eclipse console.

Comment: I can paste the code as well if you want to see it.

Comment: I expect that would help, yes - the question does not seem answerable in its present condition.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.